# How to display input validation errors under their corresponding inputs?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, if there are validation errors, they're all printed at the top of the page as `<li>` elements in a `<ul>` element. I wanna make to so that if there's a `The username field is required.` error to have it under the username input and likewise for the password error. How do I do that?

signIn view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{$error}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action='{{ route('signin') }}' method='POST'>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input class='input' type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' value='{{ Request::old('username') }}'>

        <label>Password</label>
        <input class='input' type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' value='{{ Request::old('password') }}'>

        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button class='Submit' type='submit'>Log In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

signIn function:

```
public function signIn(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:5|max:12'
        ]);

        $username = $request['username'];
        $password = $request['password'];
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])){
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Output the errors or different text in the correct location.  Personally I'd look at using a soft check via client side and then a hard check on server side.

Comment: What do you mean by soft check and hard check?

Comment: you should take a look at the auth login view laravel comes with, it does that very thing

Comment: for example an email address - plenty of validators out there that will do a check to see if it meets RFC requirements, but many aren't fully RFC compliant.  So you maybe do a soft check for something, an @ something a dot and then 2+ characters.  Allow the user to post (soft check is done, it passes) and then server side do the real check with `filter_var` and `getmxrr` and return to input if needed.  In 15k email addresses that were accepted wtih no verification I found errors in the domain (valid format, no actual registration for that domain, etc) in almost 2k of them....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal way would be to create a partial so you are not repeating the same block of code OR if you want to update what the error is wrapped in, it is in one place.

In **views/partials**, create **invalid.blade.php** with the following HTML

```
@if($errors->has($field))
    <span>{{ $errors->first($field) }}</span>
@endif
```

This checks the errors array to make sure the error for a particular field exists. The first() method takes the first error for that field from the error array (some fields may have multiple errors).

Now, under any input field, just add the following line, replacing **FIELD_NAME** with the name of the input field you are directly under (ie: username)

```
@include('partials.invalid', ['field' => 'FIELD_NAME')
```

Comment: I assume those ‘’ are used accidentally since the code doesn't work with them but works fine if I replace them with ''.

Comment: Correct. Typing from a iPhone does not give you the option for straight single quotes. Once i am at a computer, I will edit my answer.